# Regular Expression match letters and numbers together with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Html input has to validate the below type of strings. Total length should be 9. and first 3 letters are ABC and it want change. reset of 6 are numbers.

Sample Strings : `ABC000123` , `ABC000001` , `ABC004000`

ABC letters not change (Static) and other six numbers should have 0-9 values with leading zeros.

Example : UX143ABC000001 **<-wrong**

Example : ABC000001 **<-correct**

**My Frist** expression :   `/^(ABC){1}[0-9]{6,6}$/g`
**Second Expression** : `/^(ABC){1}\d{6}$/g`

```
$('#smarttag_pp_ex').keyup(function(e) {
     var txt = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
     var txt_ = new RegExp('^ABC[0-9]{6,6}');
        if(txt_.test(txt)) {
             console.log(true);
          }else{
        console.log(false);
     }                
 });
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has made no attempt at solving the problem. This question is just about how regular expressions work.

Comment: Try `^ABC\d{6}$`

Comment: Both the current expressions work, there is no issue with them (besides writing them in a clearer form).

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `^ABC\d{6}$`

If you want to restrict 6th digit being 0 (zero) use: [`^ABC(?!0{6})\d{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/g4WmTo/1)

**Details**:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line

```html
<form action="#">
  <input pattern="^ABC(?!0{6})\d{6}$" required >
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `d{3}(?:[1-9]\d{2}|\d{2}[1-9]|010)$` Can you explain this part?

Comment: @Elshan Updated! Don't use regex I posted before edit because it's not accurate (fails), use `^ABC(?!0{6})\d{6}$` instead.